# Is there an MacOS 9 skin for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, themes

If it makes a difference, I'm running 10.5.

I've been looking for quite some time, but I can't really seem to find anything.

### Edit

I'm not necessarily looking for identical usability. I just miss the old "look and feel".

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it for two reasons.

1. I've never seen *any* "skin" for OS X.
2. The two operating systems are fundamentally different. You don't have a control strip, you have a dock, you don't have an application switcher in the corner, your preferences were under the apple menu, etc.

In order to create a skin you would have to close down virtually every native process (Finder, Dock, whatever drives the menu bar) and overlay these with custom built applications. I don't even know if that's possible not to mention speed would probably be shot in the foot.

Your best bet would be to simply run a PPC virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for describing this. I wasn't necessarily saying everything had to be in the same place it used to be. I just miss the old look and feel.

Comment: There are skins for OS X, see my answer for a bit of hope.

Comment: Ever since they unified the theme in 10.5 I believe it would get much harder to change it.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Magnifique](http://magnifique.pcwizcomputer.com/) but it seems to be all but dead. You can [download it](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/download/magnifique) from the download link on [i use this](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/magnifique). But be ware it seems that it breaks Snow Leopard. Only use it with Leopard. Also, it seems like the server that held all the themes is no longer available and so you will have to search for themes via Google. But [I couldn't find anything](http://www.google.com/search?q=magnifique+theme+mac+os+9).

There's also [ShapeShifter](http://www.unsanity.com/haxies/shapeshifter/) which would apply [skins](http://interfacelift.com/themes-mac/) to OS X 10.4.X but not higher.